# WPDB Insert or if exists Update

Tags: database, wpdb, sql

I'm not crazy familiar with WPDB or SQL in general but I have a custom table for my project and I'm trying to assign some metadata to it. What I'd "like" to happen is if a row exists, update it and if not insert it. I've read both Insert and Update in the WPDB Codex but neither really went into an "either or" situation. I thought i could work with update, so my code so far looks like this:

```
$wpdb->update(
    $wpdb->prepare(
        $wpdb->prefix.'item_info',
        array(
            'post_id'       => $post_id,
            'item_stock'    => $item_stock
        ),
        array('post_id' => $post_id)
    )
);
```

Does WordPress have anything like an "IF exists Update, ELSE Insert", or do I need to run custom SQL to achieve this, or do I need to query the database first to see if an ID exists in my table THEN decide whether to update it or insert it?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

First, you are using `prepare` incorrectly. You seem to have `$wpdb->update`'s arguments wrapped  in `$wpdb->prepare` like that. That won't work. In effect, you are passing `update` a single argument-- the output of `prepare`. Try something simple like the following and you will see why that won't work:

```
$post_id = 123;
$item_stock = 567;
var_dump(
  $wpdb->prepare(
    $wpdb->prefix.'item_info',
    array(
        'post_id'       => $post_id,
        'item_stock'    => $item_stock
    ),
    array('post_id' => $post_id)
  )
);
```

[And `$wpdb->update()` runs `prepare` for you](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9.1/src/wp-includes/wp-db.php#L1761).

Second, if this were me, I skip the helper function bloat and write a proper `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` query:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO {$wpdb->prefix}item_info (post_id,item_stock) VALUES (%d,%s) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE item_stock = %s";
// var_dump($sql); // debug
$sql = $wpdb->prepare($sql,$post_id,$item_stock,$item_stock);
// var_dump($sql); // debug
$wpdb->query($sql);
```

This assumes that `post_id` is a [`UNIQUE` index or `PRIMARY KEY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html). If your table structure is what I think it is, let the database handle it.

Comment: This was insanely useful... Thanks for your time s_ha_dum!

Comment: Prepare returns false for me - no other db errors. If running the query manually in phpmyadmin it works as expected. Also checked that variables are what they should be .. Any ideas?

Comment: What if post_id isn't the PRIMARY KEY?

Answer (score 37):

Have you tried `$wpdb->replace`. According to WP Codex:

Replace a row in a table if it exists or insert a new row in a table if the row did not already exist.

I have tried myself in some plugins and it does the work when trying to avoid unique IDs duplication errors, etc.

[More info in the codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/replace/)

Comment: This worked for me while custom query did not - thanks for mentioning replace()

Comment: This is the correct answer to the question.

Comment: it is worth noting that `$wpdb->replace` is a destructive overwrite of the entire record, whereas `$wpdb->update` only updates the specific fields included in the `$data` array

Comment: This function doesn't do the replacing for me at the moment. It duplicates the same rows. Can be a PRIMARY KEY (id) field the cause that prevents the replacement to happen? I can't see info on it in the Codex.

Comment: I figured it out: To mitigate this replacement issue, it's also required to apply the UNIQUE constraint to specific columns at table creation, thus making unique rows possible.

Comment: @ViktorBorítás - or rather duplicate rows impossible?

Answer (score 7):

You can try and update the table using `$wpdb->update`, I am using the id in the following code, but you can use any criteria.

```
$result = $wpdb->update($tableName, $info, array('id' => $info["id"]));
//If nothing found to update, it will try and create the record.
if ($result === FALSE || $result < 1) {
    $wpdb->insert($tableName, $info);
}
```

**Update() result output**

- `$result === FALSE` : Fail
- `$result === 0` : Success, but nothing updated
- `$result > 1`: Success and updated

Comment: If the values are the same then MySQL will not update the row, so the affected row count will be 0.

Answer (score -1):

You should check if the row exists first.

Most likely you'll want to try to get the ID or primary key for the row you're trying to update, then `$wpdb->update` if it does or `$wpdb->insert` of it doesn't

Comment: An example of how to check if the ID or primary key exists would really make this a useful answer. This is _almost_ like reiterating the question.

Answer (score -1):

use `$wpdb->insert`, `$wpdb->insert` can insert and update too.. IN 2023

EDIT
`$wpdb->insert` not update the row , use `$wpdb->replace`

Comment: An important distinction to note is that `wpdb::replace()` does delete then insert if a duplicate is found - it does not perform a `wpdb::update()`, which needs to be considered per usecase.