# CreateOrUpdate in Wordpress

Tags: database, wpdb

the laravel framework has a handy function that is called [updateOrCreate()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#upserts).

How can I do something like this in wordpress, whereas `Flight` is the model in laravel and could be replaced by `$wpdb`:

```
$flight = Flight::updateOrCreate(
    ['departure' => 'Oakland', 'destination' => 'San Diego'],
    ['price' => 99, 'discounted' => 1]
);
```

Does something like this also exists for `$wpdb`?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: It might be difficult to answer this correctly without an example of when you might want it in WordPress, it isn't clear what the WP equivalent of a Laravel model is that you have in mind. Generally though, using raw SQL is a code smell and indicates a wrong turn has been taken. `wpdb` methods are a close second. This usually implies a developer who is unaware of custom post types, meta, and taxonomies Have you checked the WPDB documentation?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not too badly mistaken, I don't think there's a similar method in `$wpdb`. `replace`, https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/#replace-row, is kind of like that, but not quite as sophisticated I believe.

You probably need to build a helper function for that yourself, which wraps `update`, `insert` and a bit of logic together. Or use `query` method with custom sql string as suggested here, [WPDB Insert or if exists Update](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/145007/wpdb-insert-or-if-exists-update#145112).